# How do I stop Redmine from automatically referencing issues?

Tags: redmine, wiki, textile

When I am working on a page for the Wiki, I would like to put a couple of numerical list items and have centred image on the page inbetween steps, like so:

```
# Step 1
# Step 2

p=. !someimage.png!
Figure 1 - Image Caption

#3 Step 3
# Step 4
```

But when Redmine renders Step 3, it automatically references Issue #3 instead of continuing the numbering at "3." I have read on the [Textile Syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textile_%28markup_language%29#Emphasized_text) Wiki that using `#3` would start the numbering at "3." but this is not the case in the Redmine Wiki.

Is there any way to stop this behaviour? I have looked into other solutions but I was not able to retain centred images when trying to force the ordered list to continue numbering.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
# Step 1
# Step 2

  p=. !someimage.png!
  Figure 1 - Image Caption
# Step 3
# Step 4
```

Remind: Redmine is based on textile but has its own tags.

Comment: Thank you, the double-space indentation worked great. Odd fix, but I'm glad you took the time to help me out!